# How to get avarge height from dictionary only for man

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am writing python program..I wrote dictionary with name, gender and height:

```
persons = [
('Julie', 'female', 172),
('Lucca', 'male', 190),
('Vera', 'female', 165),
('Mike', 'male', 183),
('Ann', 'female', 150),
('Teo', 'male', 179)
]
```

I wrote to print out man names who are taller than 180:

```
for i in persons:
name, gender, height = i
if gender == 'male':
    if height > 180:
        print(name)
```

Now I want to calculate avarage height of all MEN (without women). I try this but I get wrong answer:

```
sum = 0
for i in persons:
    name, gender, height = i
    sum += height
    if gender == 'male':
        average = sum/3
print(average)
```

I get wrong number, output supposed to be: 184
Also how could I replace number 3 with number of mens? I mean that program will automatically know that in dictionary are 3 males

```
average = sum/3
```

Comment: `if spol == 'M'` should this be `if spol == 'male'`?

Comment: (1) `persons` is not a *dictionary* but a *list of tuples*. (2) fix your indentation.

Comment: Sorry I forget to change names, because I am doing it in my language. I will edit the post. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: When calculating average you need to divide once. Your code divides everytime it finds a male

Comment: To compute the mean, in the loop count the number of men _and_ keep a running total of their heights. When the loop finishes, you can then calculate the mean height.

Comment: Also, you need to add to the total _only if the person is male_. Your code now adds all heights

Comment: Thank you all for the tips and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only want the average of all males, you needs to add to teh sum only when the person is male, also let a counter run so that you can calculate the average dynamically

```
persons = [
('Julie', 'female', 172),
('Lucca', 'male', 190),
('Vera', 'female', 165),
('Mike', 'male', 183),
('Ann', 'female', 150),
('Teo', 'male', 179)
]
vsota = 0
povprecje_m = 0
countr = 0
for i in persons:
    ime, spol, visina = i
    
    if spol == 'male':
      vsota += visina
      countr = countr +1
povprecje_m = vsota/countr
print(povprecje_m)
print()
```

Comment: Thank youuu so much!! And I am sorry because I forgot to change names to english. Thanks for the effort and help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `statistics.mean` to do this for you:

```py
import statistics

persons = [
('Julie', 'female', 172),
('Lucca', 'male', 190),
('Vera', 'female', 165),
('Mike', 'male', 183),
('Ann', 'female', 150),
('Teo', 'male', 179)
]

print(statistics.mean(height for _, gender, height in persons if gender == 'male'))
```

Output:

```
184
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using List comprehension (if you're familiar with them)

```
# Generate list of male heights
male_heights = [height for name, sex, height in persons if sex == 'male']

# Avg is sum/number (number of male heights)
avg = sum(male_heights)/len(male_heights)
# Out: 184.0
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what language is in the bottom code sample but I re-did the code with my own variables and got it to work. There are a couple problems with your original.

For example:

```
   vsota = 0
for i in osebe:
    ime, spol, visina = i
    vsota += visina
    if spol == 'M':
        povprecje_m = vsota/3
print(povprecje_m)
print()
```

In this: vsota is an integer and visina is a string. Also, you are adding the vinsina (which I assume is height) before you determine if the person is male. This can be overcome by only adding to the count if the person is male. This is simply a placing issue. Here is the fix:

```
height_count = 0
for i in persons:
    name, gender, height = i
    if gender == 'male':
        height_count += float(height)

povprecje_m = height_count/3

print(povprecje_m)
```

To make the average dynamic, all you would have to do is add a counter to track how many times the IF statement executed. This can be done by:

```
complete_counter = 0
height_count = 0
for i in persons:
    name, gender, height = i
    if gender == 'male':
        height_count += float(height)
        complete_counter += 1

povprecje_m = height_count/complete_counter

print(povprecje_m)
```

Comment: Why convert height to a float? All height values are an integer.

Comment: I am really sorry because I forgot to change names to english. Thank you so much for the effort and help!! I fixed it and now I get the correct answer :D